# Limiting the scope of jquery script to immediate ancestors

Tags: jquery, gravity-forms-plugin

I've written this script to find `<fieldset>` tags with a child containing `gfield_error`, and add a class `wow-error` into that `<fieldset>`.

The problem is it works too well and if it finds `gfield_error` anywhere on the page it adds the class to every `<fieldset>` on the page, not just those with a child that has `gfield_error`.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
$(':has(.gfield_error) > fieldset').addClass('wow-error');
});

<fieldset class="gfieldset">
    <legend class="gfieldset-legend ">Name</legend>
    <ul class="gform_fields">
        <li id="field_2_95" class="gfield gfield_error">
                <p>Some content</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</fieldset>
```

I'm sure it's an elementary mistake, could anyone offer guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first thought is to turn it around — find any `.gfield_error` *then* get the gfieldset it is within, using [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```js
$('#demo').on('click', function() {
    $('.gfield_error')
        .closest('fieldset.gfieldset')
        .addClass('wow-error');
});
```

```css
fieldset {
  margin: 1em;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
.wow-error {
  background-color: lightyellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<fieldset class="gfieldset">
  <legend class="gfieldset-legend">Name</legend>
  <ul class="gform_fields">
    <li id="field_2_95" class="gfield gfield_error">
      <p>Some content in matching fieldset</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="not-gfieldset">
  <legend class="gfieldset-legend">Name</legend>
  <ul class="gform_fields">
    <li id="field_2_96" class="gfield gfield_error">
      <p>Some content in non-matching fieldset<br>
         This is a fieldset but it's not a .gfieldset, so even though
         if contains a .gfield_error it does not get selected.</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="gfieldset">
  <legend class="gfieldset-legend">Name</legend>
  <ul class="gform_fields">
    <li id="field_2_97" class="gfield not-gfield_error">
      <p>Some content in matching fieldset w/o gfield_error.<br>
         This is a .gfieldset but it does not contain a .gfield_error</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="gfieldset">
  <legend class="gfieldset-legend">Name</legend>
  <ul class="gform_fields">
    <li id="field_2_98" class="gfield gfield_error">
      <p>Another matching fieldset</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</fieldset>

<button type="button" id="demo">Demonstrate</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell without any "real" markup... But I can suggest the following loop:

```
$('.gfieldset :has(.gfield_error)').each(function(){
  $(this).addClass('wow-error');
});
```

So that should loop through all `.gfieldset` that has at least a child having the `gfield_error`.

`$(this)` is the targeted `.gfieldset` matching element...

```js
$('.gfieldset:has(.gfield_error)').each(function() {
  $(this).addClass('wow-error');
});
```

```css
.wow-error {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset class="gfieldset">
  <legend class="gfieldset-legend ">Name</legend>
  <ul class="gform_fields">
    <li id="field_2_95" class="gfield gfield_error">
      <p>Some content</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="gfieldset">
  <legend class="gfieldset-legend ">Name</legend>
  <ul class="gform_fields">
    <li id="field_2_95" class="gfield"><!-- No error class here -->
      <p>Some content</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</fieldset>
```

So in short... `:has(.gfield_error)` here is the collection of ALL the elements having a child with the `gfield_error` class. That can result in a huge collection of all the elements parent of the real targeted elemment.

Then you look for a CHILD `<fieldset>` element on which to add a class... Sadly... That `fieldset` is a parent of the matching lookup.

Feel free to ask... Since re-reading myself sounds esoteric. lol

---

**EDIT**

Another idea... Which is possibly clearer. You could start form the each element having the `.gfield_error` class and climb up to the [.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) `<fieldset>` parent to add the `.wow-error` class.

```js
$('.gfield_error').each(function() {
  $(this).closest("fieldset").addClass('wow-error');
});
```

```css
.wow-error {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset class="gfieldset">
  <legend class="gfieldset-legend ">Name</legend>
  <ul class="gform_fields">
    <li id="field_2_95" class="gfield gfield_error">
      <p>Some content</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="gfieldset">
  <legend class="gfieldset-legend ">Name</legend>
  <ul class="gform_fields">
    <li id="field_2_95" class="gfield"><!-- No error class here -->
      <p>Some content</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</fieldset>
```